# Connecting to RedShift results in SSL error: certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm attempting to connect to a RedShift database via Python 2.7 / sqlalchemy (1.2.14) / psycopg2 (2.7.6.1), but am running into issues configuring the SSL properties:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://(username:password)@(server):5439/(database)?sslmode=verify-full').connect()
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL error: certificate verify failed

I've completed all of the steps per Amazon's instruction:

1. [Transitioning to ACM Certificates for SSL Connections: Using Other SSL Connection Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-transitioning-to-acm-certs.html#connecting-transitioning-to-acm-other-ssl-types)
2. [Install and Configure the Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver on Microsoft Windows Operating Systems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/install-odbc-driver-windows.html)

So I now have the latest version of redshift-ca-bundle.crt saved as root.crt to my %APPDATA%\postgresql folder. I also have the 32-bit and 64-bit drivers installed, and system DSN configured in both ODBC Administrator tools (32 & 64) that successfully verify a server connection.

What am I missing to properly configure the SSL in my Python code in order to connect? I do know that SSL is required to connect, but am not sure how to provide the correct certificate.

Comment: I noticed that sqlalchemy installed the exact same redshift-ca-bundle.crt file to the following directory. Not sure if I need to use this somehow? C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy_redshift

Comment: SSL might be required but does the certificate need to be verified? You could try `ssl-mode=require` instead. Also, I'm no psycopg2 expert, but where are you using an ODBC DSN in that connection?

Comment: Same error occurs when changing to ssl-mode=require. I'm not sure on the ODBC DSN part -- pretty new to this, to be honest. But I am going to try using an ODBC connection.

Comment: To ignore certificates, try this: `engine = sa.create_engine('redshift+redshift_connector://user:passwordv@host:port/db',connect_args={'sslmode': "allow"})`

Answer (score 1):

I was successfully able to connect using pypyodbc and the following connection string (details redacted):

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)};'
                              'Server=<server>;'
                              'Database=<database>;'
                              'UID=<login>;'
                              'PWD=<password>;'
                              'Port=5439;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=True')
```